# Crystal Reports - Performance Problems with Multi Sub-reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

Working with SAP Crystal Reports for Enterprise;

Case is with a main report having lots of subreport and passing data to each individual subreport.

Main report is depicted below:

```
Report Header - ReportHeader_Subreport
Page Header   - PageHeader_Subreport
Body Section1 - BodySubreport-1
Body Section2 - BodySubreport-2
.
Body SectionN - BodySubreport-N
Report Footer - Report_Subreport
Page Footer   - PageFooter_Subreport
```

By sending outer parameters, I show only the required subreports by the user. Forexample while

```
Enter visibility parameters: 1-2-3-4-..-n
```

shows all the subreports,

```
Enter visibility parameters: 1
```

only shows the BodySubreport-1 as intended.

**However** there is a major speed problem in here and *I think CR renders all the reports **then** suppresses according to parameters.*

**Is it possible to prevent CR to render all suppressed sections but to render only non-suppressed sections determined by outer parameters**? Or is it because I suppress the sections but not the subreports (which i believe that is not the case).

Thank you.

Comment: Outer paramter sill show effect in CR that is only display part but how much time it is taking to get the data from database? have you checked that and what is the amount of data getting retrived?

Comment: Lets say, after i completly remove BodySubreport-1, report runs in t time. After adjusting db connections etc, If i run BodySubreport-1 only in a different main report, it runs in 2t time.

If user wants to see all reports, t+2t = 3t time is acceptable wait time and we have no problem with that.

But if user doesn't want to see BodySection-1 specificaly, user wants to wait for the report t time instead of same 3t time.

Comment: in that case why don't you try `ondemand subreport.` It is just a thought

Comment: In that case user needs to click on the subreport string to see it rather it is visible or not. Which, in our case; user exports to .pdf without viewing it.
So, ondemand subreport is no good for us unfortunatelly.

Comment: I don't know about the filtering you are applying but only solution I can suggest is filter the report to the extent possible so that only required data is retrived from database and displayed

Comment: I'm just thinking out loud right now, and don't know if this will work, but pass the parameter into the sub report, once on the sub report use the parameter to intentionally "fail" the report (i.e. pass a value that doesn't exist).

Comment: I tried using none existing parameter before but nevertheless CR still connects DB and runs query anyways. I need something to prevent running query at all if outer parameter already suppresses the section which holds that subreport.

Comment: Are you sure that it is the number of subreports used, and not just one slow subreport? What do the results of _Report -> Performance Information_ show?